# Writing an embeddable JS widget safely

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

**Objective**
Create an embeddable Javascript widget that users can embed on their page with a few lines of async supporting Javascript without breaking their page to load a gallery + lightbox. Having read several threads on SO on the subject, none of them appears to completely answer the questions below:

**Questions**
While isolating the CSS styles we will be using to ensure our widget does not overwrite anything on the user's page or vice versa is trivial, I'd like to know:

1. What are the best practices for loading other plugins/dependencies (eg: jQuery-UI, Galleria ) in the safest way possible ? If the user's site already has loaded some of the plugins we are going to load, how do we prevent interference ?
2. What are the disadvantages to using a loader script (as described [here](http://shootitlive.com/2012/07/developing-an-embeddable-javascript-widget/)) that is embedded directly with a script and async tag into the target page ? This would result in the user only having to embed a single line of code in their page, instead of the multi lined script tag generation method common to services such as Google Analytics and Facebook.
3. When using jQuery in a widget, is the noConflict() method the best way to go ? How would this work with other plugins that also rely on jQuery ?

Thanks for your input in advance

Comment: This is a quite complex task, especially when you depend on heavy libraries and styles. I can recommend a good book on this topic: http://thirdpartyjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have actually read that book, and they specifically leave out considerations when writing widgets that depend on other plugins. It also does not talk about 'loader' widgets that I'm seeing more and more of these days